# How are .debdiffs applied?

Tags: package-management, apache2, deb, debian

Came by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/apache2/+bug/1534538). How do I apply the [.debdiff](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/274195186/fix_aliasmatch_long_uri.debdiff)?

Here is the most relevant-seeming guidance I've found:

```
# Apply a debdiff patch.
# - PKGNAME: Name of the package
# - DEBDIFF: Deb diff file.
# - RESPACKAGE: Resulting package of debuild

# Neccesary packages to make the deb package
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot devscripts

apt-get source PKGNAME
sudo apt-get build-dep PKGNAME
cd PKGNAME-*
patch -p1 < ../DEBDIFF
debuild -uc -us
sudo dpkg -i ../RESPACKAGE

# Thanks to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuPackagingGuide/BuildFromDebdiff
```

(https://snipt.net/gjulian/apply-a-debdiff-patch/)

Here is my confusion/concern:

1. The snippet is ancient. Is it still relevant?
2. Where is the `PCKGNAME`?
3. `fix_aliasmatch_long_uri.debdiff` is the `DEBDIFF`?
4. What's the `RESPACKAGE`?
5. `apt-get` @ `root/`?

Comment: See http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/traditional-packaging.html#applying-a-debdiff and http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm . It is a patch.

Comment: Since the bug fix is committed to trusty, I wound up just updating ubuntu.